# Django-How to make the django inbuilt auth view recognize the customized form

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I am using the django inbuilt auth url and views

so, in url.py

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

in views.py

```
from MyApp.forms import *
from django.contrib.auth.views import *
```

I want to customize the SetPasswordForm which is used by django inbuit view`password_reset_confirm` function as the I need to do more checking with the new_password1

In my forms.py　I have the my customized SetPasswordForm like below (with the SetPasswordForm imported from `contrib.auth.forms already`

```
class SetPasswordForm(SetPasswordForm):
    error_messages = {
        'invalid_password': _("Please enter a valid password as instructed"),
        'password_mismatch': _("The two password fields didn't match."),
    }
    new_password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, min_length=6, label='New Password' )
    new_password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, min_length=6, label='Confirm new password')

    def clean_new_password1(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")

        # password must contain both Digits and Alphabets
        # password cannot contain other symbols
        if password1.isdigit() or password1.isalpha() or not password1.isalnum():
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['invalid_password'],
                code='invalid_password',
            ) 
        return password1
```

Could anyone help explain why the django inbuilt view could not recognize my customized SetPasswordForm and if it is possible to do so?

If it is not meant to be recognizing the customized SetPasswordForm, that would mean I have to redefine the url and views parameters(to specify the form to be used) am I right?Correct me if there are any errors

Thank you very much.

Comment: you need to manually pass your custom form as keyword argument `set_password_form` to `password_reset_confirm` view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override the URL to pass your custom form class as a view keyword argument. Details in [How to override a view from an external Django app](http://blog.yourlabs.org/post/19777151073/how-to-override-a-view-from-an-external-django-app).

Comment: hi.thank you very much for answering, now I understand the logic behind and have tried so, but the view is still not recongnizing, would you mind take a look at the follow-up qustions and help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17438964/why-django-inbuilt-auth-views-not-recognizing-the-customized-form  thank you!

Comment: @Mona The particular url for password_reset_confirm needs to have more in the URL, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix up your URLs a bit.

In your `urls.py`, this...

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    ...
]
```

Needs to be...

```
import django.contrib.auth.views as auth_views
from myapp.forms import SetPasswordForm

urlpatterns = [
    ...

    url(r'^accounts/reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
    auth_views.password_reset_confirm, {'set_password_form': SetPasswordForm}, name='password_reset_confirm'),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    ...
]
```

It is critical that the `password_reset_confirm` url is above the other url.