# why django inbuilt auth views not recognizing the customized form?

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I understand that when we need to make the django inbuilt views, parameter specification should be made before the inbuilt view function could use it.

now I want to customize the form for django auth view`password_reset_confirm`

and in the url, I import my customized form

```
from Myapp.forms import PasswordSetForm
from django.contrib.auth import urls,views
```

and for the url

```
url(r'^accounts/ ^reset/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13})-(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$  ',
        'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm',{'set_password_form':PasswordSetForm},
        name='password_reset_confirm'),
url(r'^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

in my form.py i import the original `SetPasswordForm` that is used as default form by django `password_reset_confirm` funciton

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import SetPasswordForm
```

and then customize the form

```
class PasswordSetForm(SetPasswordForm):
    error_messages = {
        'invalid_password': _("Please enter a valid password as instructed"),
        'password_mismatch': _("The two password fields didn't match."),
    }


    #new_password1 = forms.CharField(label=_("New password"),
    #                                widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    #new_password2 = forms.CharField(label=_("New password confirmation"),
    #                                widget=forms.PasswordInput)


    new_password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, min_length=6, label='New Password' )
    new_password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, min_length=6, label='Confirm new password')

    def clean_new_password1(self):
        new_password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("new_password1")

        # password must contain both Digits and Alphabets
        # password cannot contain other symbols
        if new_password1.isdigit() or new_password1.isalpha() or not new_password1.isalnum():
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['invalid_password'],
                code='invalid_password',
            ) 
        return new_password1
```

as you could see more checking are done for the new_password1

But after trying many times the page is still using the default SetpasswordForm as the default labels for the two password is displayed in my html instead of my customized label(in the html `{{form.new_password2.label}}` is used to display label) and no additional checking on the new_password1 is done

I have tried to create another MyPasswordSetForm that does not inherit the SetPassordForm and pass this to the `password_reset_confirm` but it does not make any difference, the default form is still used.

I have googled lot and ask questions on this, seems this is the right way to go, but What could be the problem here?

Thank you very much for helping.

Comment: It actually seems correct, how do you know that it's still using `SetPasswordForm`? Is not clear in your question.

Comment: In my html I use the form.new_passord2.label, so from the label output   I could see that the default form is used(as you can see my label for the new_password2 is different from the default form) and also, no error checking on the new_password1 is done(e.g. min lengh of 6, should contain digits&alpha). but it would do the error checking of comparing the two password which is in the default form

Comment: Did you double checked that the actual view is getting called? Also, maybe you've done it but try restarting the server again. Your code seems well.

Comment: Please, show us your urls.py file. I've made the same today, and works

Comment: @PauloBu yea, the first point you mentioned should be where the problem is as I have added a few print "message" in the customized form,so if the view is accessed message should be print in the server terminal, but nothing is print when i am accessing the reset link. I have updated the url so that it is exactly the same as the default url(this could be copied from the Pagenotfound which display all the url) but the view is stilled not used.

Comment: @lalo can i have a look at how yours is done? there are several urls that are not relevant to the auth process, so I didn't show them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops, that URL regexp looks wrong wrong wrong:

```
r'^accounts/ ^reset/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13})-(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$  '
```

It should be:

```
r'^accounts/reset/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13})-(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$'
```

Comment: sorry initially I used the accounts/reset/... but is was not working so I copied the url of accounts/ ^reset/... from the PageNotFound(404) which displayed all the auth.urls.  Also, I think the reason my initial accounts/reset/... is not working is because of the blanks before the /$' that I didn't notice. it was amazing, thank you so much..